# How to check UNIQUE using multiple column in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

I have a city state country table. Multiple cities have the same city name but I need to check the unique for same state same city name! how can I do It?

```
 $validation->setRule('city_name', 'City Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[cities.city_name]');
```

This is (above) my code. I need unique should check both column fr ex: city_name also state_id something like below,

```
 $validation->setRule('city_name', 'City Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[cities.city_name,cities.state_id]');
```

Please Help me with create and update in CI4! the above code also not working!

Answer (score -1):

You code need a bit of change

```
$validation->setRule('city_name', 'City Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[cities.city_name,cities.state_id]');
```

to

```
$validation->setRule('city_name', 'City Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[cities.city_name,state_id, {state_id}]');
```

**state_id** is the value of the matched incoming field.

For more detail, you can look [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html).

Comment: I have tried your code but not working.. duplicate entry is creating.. unique error not showing.

Comment: @sridhar Can you share the POST variable names as you set in form?

Comment: state_id only... $validation->setRule('city_name', 'City Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[cities.city_name,state_id, {state_id}]');
$validation->setRule('state_id', 'State', 'trim|required');